# Unmarshall multiple XML sources into a single object JAXB

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, relationship

I am using JAXB to unmarshall XML into objects from a REST service. The issue is that I do not have a way right not to represent relationships. So, I was wonderinf if anyone knows if you can unmarshall into parts of an object from different sources.

For example, I have an incident table, which relate to a problem table. If I want the incident and the problem, I need to objects.

XML:

```
<name>issue 1</name>
<problem>primary key to problem</problem>

<name> problem </name>
<incident>primary key to incident.</incident>
```

Objects:

```
private string name;
private string problem/incident;
```

What I want instead:

```
  private string name;
  private Problem problem;
```

See, instead of a string I want an object type, but the issue would be is that object type comes from a different XML source.